Spring Boot app: No ServletWebServerFactory bean in context
When attempting to run my web app, I encountered the following issue:
Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context
I've searched on Stack Overflow and found similar questions, but none of the provided solutions resolved my problem. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated
I attempted to integrate security features into my web app by adding entities such as Utilisateur Entity and Role entity, along with their corresponding repositories. Additionally, I configured Spring Security components including AuthEntryPoint, AuthTokenFilter, and JwtUtils.
However, after implementing these changes, I encountered the issue mentioned earlier: 'Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.'
I acknowledge that there may be other errors in my app, but at this point, I'm solely focused on identifying the cause of this particular problem. Your assistance in resolving this matter is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.
I meticulously followed the solutions provided in similar questions on Stack Overflow but none of them resolved my issue. Below is an excerpt from my pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.IsoShift</groupId>
    <artifactId>Backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Backend</name>
    <description>Backend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Main FIle :
package com.isoshift.backend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }
}

webSecurityConfig.java :
package com.isoshift.backend.security;

import com.isoshift.backend.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import com.isoshift.backend.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import com.isoshift.backend.security.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity // Spring Boot 3
public class WebSecurityConfig { // extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}


AuthController :
package com.isoshift.backend.Controleur;


import com.isoshift.backend.payload.request.LoginRequest;
import com.isoshift.backend.payload.request.SignupRequest;
import com.isoshift.backend.payload.response.JwtResponse;
import com.isoshift.backend.payload.response.MessageResponse;
import com.isoshift.backend.Entity.Role;
import com.isoshift.backend.Entity.Utilisateur;
import com.isoshift.backend.Service.Constant.ERole;
import com.isoshift.backend.repository.RoleRepo;
import com.isoshift.backend.repository.UtilisateurRepo;
import com.isoshift.backend.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
import com.isoshift.backend.security.service.UserDetailsImpl;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UtilisateurRepo userRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepo roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt,
                //userDetails.getId(),
                userDetails.getUsername(),
                //userDetails.getEmail(),
                roles));
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
        int matEmpInt = 0;
        try {
            matEmpInt = Integer.parseInt(signUpRequest.getMATEMP());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        if (userRepository.existsByMATEMP(matEmpInt)) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }

        /*if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in use!"));
        }*/

        // Create new user's account
        Utilisateur user = new Utilisateur(matEmpInt,
                encoder.encode((signUpRequest.getNOMEMP() + signUpRequest.getPRNEMP())));

        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.Role_utilisateur)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                if (role.equals("admin")) {
                    Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.Role_admin)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(adminRole);
                } else {
                    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.Role_utilisateur)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
    }
}



After further investigation, I realized that I had inadvertently removed a crucial dependency from my project:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

Adding this dependency resolved the issue I was experiencing with the missing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean in the context. Everything now works as expected. Thank you for your assistanc
